# Threading + multiple windows causing strange errors

Tags: multithreading, swift, macos

I have 2 windows in swift, one is like a login dialog which sends an `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` to a server to get authenticated. Once it gets the response, the window is supposed to close.

When I close the Window (either from the login window class or main window clasS) I get these errors:

`This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.`

I have tried all manner of background threads etc. But I think the issue is that I am closing the window why the asynch NSURLConnection request is still hanging.

My code to send the async request from the login window:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
                let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary
                let result: NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                let expectedString = "special auth string"!
                if(result == expectedString) {
                    self.callback.loginOK()
                } else {
                    self.output.stringValue = result
                }
                return
            })
        })
```

The callback member of the class is the parent view contoller that spawns it, I then close the login window using `loginVC.view.window?.close()` from the main application window. That causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that  NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest will always run in a secondary thread and thus its callback will be called from that secondary thread despite you calling it explicitly from main thread. 
You don't need to wrap NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest in the main thread, instead wrap your  ' self.callback.loginOK()' to run in main thread using the dispatch_async to ensure no UI related operations take place in secondary thread.  Something like this-

```
let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
                let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary
                let result: NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() {
                let expectedString = "special auth string"!
                if(result == expectedString) {
                    self.callback.loginOK()
                } else {
                    self.output.stringValue = result
                }
              })

                return
            })
```